# Proof of the acyclic model theorem - having trouble

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I am using as a reference Spanier's text *Algebraic Topology.*

The acyclic model theorem is stated as theorem 5.3.3.

I am unable to show that the natural transformation $H_0G\to H_0G'$ is well-defined on equivalence classes. For example, if $g$ is a boundary in $G_0(X)$, how do I show that $\sum n_{ij}G'_0(f_{ij})z_j$ is also a boundary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all let us note that Spanier is little imprecise. He defines a functor $G$ from a category $\mathcal C$ with models $\mathfrak M$ to the category of chain complexes to be free if all $G_q$ are free. However, it seems to me that he really works with a collection of functors $G_q$ from $\mathcal C$ to the category of abelian groups which are free on models $\mathfrak M_q$ which *may* explicitly depend on $q$. In many cases these sets *must* even be pairwise disjoint. In Example 6, one should take $\mathfrak M_q(K) = \{ \bar s \mid s \in K, \dim s = q \}$. If we take $\mathfrak M(K) = \{ \bar s \mid s \in K \}$ for all $q$, then Spanier's $g_s = \sigma(s)$ are not contained in $C_q(\bar s)$ unless $\dim s = q$. Similarly, in Example 7 we must take $\mathfrak M_q = \{ \Delta^q \}$.

In the proof of Theorem 3 Spanier assigns to each $g_j \in G_0(M^0_j)$, $M^0_j \in\mathfrak M_0$, the unique $z_j \in H_0(G'(M^0_j))$ such that $\bar{\epsilon}([g_j])= \bar{\epsilon}'(z_j)$, where $\bar{\epsilon} : H_0(G(M_j)) \to \mathbb Z, \bar{\epsilon}' : H_0(G'(M_j)) \to \mathbb Z$ are induced by the augmentation maps, and defines $H_0(G(X)) \to H_0(G'(X))$ by
$$\left[\sum n_{ij}G_0(f_{ij})(g_j)\right] \mapsto \sum n_{ij}(f_{ij})_*(z_j) .$$
It is not clear why this is well-defined. To see this, we need a slightly modified approach. Choose $\zeta_j \in G'_0(M_j)$ such that $[\zeta_j] = z_j$ and define $\theta_0 : G_0(X) \to G'_0(X)$ by
$$\theta_0(\sum n_{ij}G_0(f_{ij})(g_j)) = \sum n_{ij}G'_0(f_{ij})(\zeta_j) .$$
Recall that the $G_0(f)(g_j)$ form a basis for $G_0(X)$, i.e. $\theta_0$ is the unique homomorphism such that $\theta_0(G_0(f)(g_j)) = G'_0(f_{ij})(\zeta_j)$. We have $\epsilon' \theta_0 = \epsilon$ because $\epsilon'G_0(f) = G'_0(f) \epsilon$ and $\epsilon(g_j) = \epsilon'(\zeta_j)$.

To see that $\theta_0$ maps boundaries to boundaries, we use the same method to construct $\theta_1 : G_1(X) \to G'_1(X)$ such that $\partial'_1\theta_1 = \theta_0 \partial_1$. This will show that Spanier's map is well-defined.

Since $\epsilon' \theta_0 \partial_1 = \epsilon \partial_1 = 0$, for each $g^1_k  \in G_1(M^1_k)$, $M^1_k \in \mathfrak M_1$, we have $\theta_0 \partial_1(g^1_k) \in \ker \epsilon'$. Since $G'$ is acyclic, we know that $\ker \epsilon' = \text{im} \partial'_1$. Hence we can choose $z^1_k \in G'_1(M^1_k)$ such that $\partial'_1(z^1_k) = \theta_0 \partial_1(g^1_k)$. Now define $\theta_1$ as $\theta_0$.

**Edited:**

After a little exchange of ideas with Patrick (see the comments) I suggest the following "pragmatic" definition of a free functor.

A category with models is a pair $(\mathcal C, \mathfrak M)$ consisting of a category $\mathcal C$ and a set $\mathfrak M$ of objects of $\mathcal C$.

Consider a functor $G : \mathcal C \to \mathbf{Ab}$ = category of abelian groups. An *$\mathfrak M$-basis* for $G$ consists of a subset $\mathfrak M_G \subset \mathfrak M$ and an element $(g_M ) \in \prod_{M  \in \mathfrak M_G} G(M)$ such that the set
$$\{G(f)(g_M) \mid M \in  \mathfrak M_G, f \in \hom(M,X) \}$$
is a basis for $G(X)$. If $G$ has an $\mathfrak M$-basis, then $G$ is called *free* on $(\mathcal C, \mathfrak M)$.

**Edited:**

In the proof of Theorem 5.3.3 Spanier refers to Theorem 5.2.8 which requires that $G'$ is acyclic in positive dimensions. The stronger assumption that $G'$ is acyclic, i.e. the additional assumption that $\tilde{H}_0(G'(M)) = H_0(\tilde{G'}(M)) = 0$ for all $M \in \mathfrak{M}$, enters when he constructs the elements $z_j \in H_0(G'(M^0_j))$ which are uniquely determined by  $\bar{\epsilon}([g_j])= \bar{\epsilon}'(z_j)$ (due to Lemma 1 and $\tilde{H}_0(G'(M_j)) = 0$). It is clear that any natural transformation $\Theta : H_0(G) \to H_0(G')$ which is induced by an augmentation preserving natural chain map must necessarily satisfy $\Theta([g_j]) = z_j$. It is then also clear that the only *candidate* for $\Theta : H_0(G(X)) \to H_0(G'(X))$ is that described above. I think it is a serious omission by Spanier not to clarify why this is well-defined, and it puzzles readers. The proof requires to use a second time $\tilde{H}_0(G'(M_j)) = 0$.

On the other hand, I think that Theorem 5.3.3 is completely covered by Theorem 5.2.8. Each augmented chain complex $C$ can be regarded as an ordinary nonnegative chain complex $C^{sh}$ by making a dimension shift of $+1$. Each augmentation preserving chain map $\phi : C \to D$ corresponds to an ordinary chain map $\phi^{sh} : C^{sh} \to D^{sh}$ which is the identity in dimension $0$. With this construction we have $\tilde{H}_q(C) = H_{q+1}(C^{sh})$. Clearly, if $G$ is free, then also $G^{sh}$ is free (in dimension $0$ we have the constant functor $X \mapsto \mathbb Z$ for which a basis is $1 \in \mathbb Z = const(M)$ for an arbitrary $M$). Also, if $G'$ is acyclic, then $(G')^{sh}$ is acyclic in positive dimensions. Now apply Theorem 5.2.8 to $id : H_0(G^{sh}) \to H_0((G')^{sh})$. Note that this is the *only* homomorphism which can be induced by an augmentation preserving natural chain map $G \to G'$ (consider the corresponding natural chain map
$G^{sh} \to (G')^{sh}$).

**Last edit:**

I just realized that the best approach would be to replace Theorem 5.2.8 by the following (with the same assumptions as in 5.2.8):

(a) Any natural transformation $\nu : G_0 \to H_0(G')$ is induced by a natural chain map $\tau : G \to G'$. This means that $\nu = \pi' \circ \tau_0$, where $\pi' : G'_0 \to H_0(G')$ is the natural quotient map.

(b) Two natural chain maps $\tau, \tau' : G \to G'$ inducing the same natural transformation $G_0 \to H_0(G')$ (or equivalently, the same natural transformation $H_0(G) \to H_0(G')$) are naturally chain homotopic.

The proof is - mutatis mutandis - the same as that of 5.2.8. The new theorem covers Spanier's theorem because

1. For any natural transformation $\theta: H_0(G) \to H_0(G')$, the composition $\theta \circ \pi : G_0 \to H_0(G')$ is a natural transformation, where $\pi : G_0 \to H_0(G)$ is the natural quotient map.
2. Each natural transformation $\nu : G_0 \to H_0(G')$ which is induced by a natural chain map $\tau : G \to G'$ induces a unique natural transformation $\theta: H_0(G) \to H_0(G)$ such that $\theta \circ \pi : G_0 \to H_0(G)$.

This variant of Theorem 5.2.8 can be used to prove Theorem 5.3.3.

Comment: Yes, Spanier does say prior to his Example 6 in section 4.2 that a functor $G$ valued in chain complexes is free if $G_q$ is free for each $q$, each of which are free in the sense previously defined. I agree the choice of basis should depend on $q$ and it doesn't look like they need to satisfy any coherence conditions between the $q$.

Comment: Ah okay, I missed that point! I shall edit my answer.

Comment: Alright, I think I understand. Thank you very much this has been bugging me for a day or two now. I was trying to work entirely with the basis for $G_0$, it didn't occur to me that I had to use the basis for $G_1$ as well.

Comment: For the record; my understanding of the notion of a category with models is a pair $(\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{M})$, where $\mathcal{M}$ is a subset of $Obj(\mathcal{C})$. We do fix one single set $\mathcal{M}$. If $F: \mathcal{C} \to \mathbf{Ab}$ is valued in the category of free Abelian groups, then a basis for $F$ is a triple $(J,S,S')$ where $J$ is a set, $S: J\to \mathcal{M}$ is a set function,and $S': J\to \coprod_{j\in J} F(S(j))$ is a $J$-indexed family of various elements, where we denote $M_j = S(j), g_j = S'(j)$. It is the structure $(J,S,S')$ which changes with $q$, not $\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: This allows us to say, on the one hand, that $G: (\mathcal{C},\mathcal{M})\to Ch(\mathbf{Ab})$ is free if there exists a basis for each $G_q$, and on the other hand that $F'$ is acyclic if each $G'(M)$ is acyclic for $M\in \mathcal{M}$. Because for the latter it makes no sense to let $\mathcal{M}$ vary with $q$.

Comment: I agree. Your function $S'$ is nothing else than an element of $\prod_{j \in J} F(S(j))$. And you can also identify $J$ with a subset $\mathcal M_F$ of $\mathcal M$ (unless you want to allow that $M_j = M_{j'}$ is possible for $j \ne j'$).

Comment: Yes I think in the general case we should insist on the possibility that $M_j =M_{j'}$ for $j\neq j'$ as it seems to arise in the intended applications that we frequently choose distinct $g_j, g_{j'}$ in the same $M_j =M_{j'}$ as becomes necessary even in the simple case where $C=M$ is the one object category but the associated free group is of dimension > 1. But my question has been answered so I will stop nitpicking! Thanks agaim